# How can I capture all char's typed into a textbox as the user types?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard

In C#, how can I capture all `char` typed into a `textbox` as the user types?

So if a user typed `Hello World` the function would capture each individual `char` and process it.

I need super exact control of all text as it comes in. I will delete from the `textbox` all invalid characters, and will allow the user to stack up certain characters and then some other character when they are used will fire of functions.

Example:

The user types the following into a `textbox`

`Blarg Blarg 600*50-90blarg`

This is how I want to operate this mess:

As each Char gets read, All alphabetic characters are discarded from memory and from the textbox, so that the user does not even see them entered.

So the first part doesn't even show up, then when the user types `6` that sticks to the textbox, and then `0`and then `0` so eventually what is displayed to the user is `600`. Then the user types `*` and this is discarded from the screen but its causes a function to fire that takes the number in the textbox and awaits the next digit.

I can handle most of this but validating user input from the keyboard is not easy in C#

So the question: Can I operate code on each char as they come right of the keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, you use the KeyPress event like so:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char c = e.KeyChar;
    // your code here
}
```

You could then parse the char info like so:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char c = e.KeyChar;

    if (c >= 48 && c <= 57)
    {
        // numeric value
        // do something
    }
    else if (c == 42)
    {
        // multiply (*)
        // do something
    }
    else if (c == 47)
    {
        // divide (/)
        // do something
    }
    else if (c == 13)
    {
        // enter key
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // discard
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `TextChanged`, but this does not give you the char pressed.

Comment: Cheers Adam, how can I stop the typed Chars loading onto the textbox? I really want to control exactly what loads into the textbox.

Comment: Please see my edit, this is one way you could do it. By setting the `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` to true you are telling the control that you've already handled the keypress and it doesn't need to do anything else, therefore it doesn't insert the key.

Comment: Adam that is awesome so many thanks! Just one more, how can I interpret the `enter` key?

Comment: The enter key is key char `13`, see the edit. For more key chars, check this ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Comment: You may find that the enter key makes an annoying noise, check out this article if you want to [remove the annoying sound](http://www.adamkdean.co.uk/blog/read/5/remove-annoying-beep-from-pressing-enter-in-textbox).

Comment: fruitition should most certainly be a real word. :)

Comment: Hah, that it should. The migration went well and is still in use today. ;)

Comment: Why use ASCII codes when you could just compare with char literals?
`if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ...`

Comment: I suppose you could do it that way, but I have always found it more intuitive to compare it to the char decimal values. Otherwise some ranges may be confusing; 'which is higher, A or a?' etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using your textbox to allow only particluar chars as input, you can try using a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763018.aspx).